# Prove that $\mu^*$ restricted to $\mathcal{B}(X)$ is a measure on $\mathcal{B}(X)$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, borel-measures

We have the following theorem:

> If $\mu^*$ is a metric outer measure, then all Borel sets in $X$ are $\mu^*$-measureable.

I have found the proof in [here](http://individual.utoronto.ca/jordanbell/notes/hausdorffmeasure.pdf), but I can't see clearly everything so I need some help.
I don't understand the part when we want to show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \nu(E_n)=\nu(E\cap F').$
It's on the 2nd page.
Could you explain me why the inequalities below are satisfied ((4) and the one above it)? Any tips will be extreamely helpful! Maybe you know other easy proofs of the theorem you can share? Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you be a little more specific? you don't get why we want to prove this equality you mention? Or rather how it's proven, i.e. the inequalities you mention. Or is it both? You can try and right down which part exactly are bot very clear. It could even maybe help you understand it yourself without any extra help.

Comment: I know why we want to prove the equality. I don't get the next steps. How do we know that $$\rho(y, F) \leq \rho(x, y) + \rho(x, F) <
\frac{1}{n(n + 1)}+\frac{1}{n + 1}$$
and why then $\rho(D_{n+1}, E_n)\geq \frac{1}{n+1}$?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

- $\rho(y, F) \leq \rho(x, y) + \rho(x, F) < \frac{1}{n(n + 1)}+\frac{1}{n + 1}=\frac{1}{n}$:

It's just a matter of choice of $x$ and $y$. The first inequality is triangle inequality. Now,  $x\in D_{n+1}$ which means (by definition of $D_{n+1}$ ) that $x \notin E_{n+1}$; in other words (by definition of $E_{n+1}$) $\rho(x,F) < \frac{1}{n+1}$. Furthermore, $y\in X$ was chosen such that $\rho (x,y)< \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$.

- $\rho(D_{n+1}, E_n)\geq \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$ :

Lets assume this not true, i.e. $\rho(D_{n+1}, E_n)< \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$. Then we can find a $x\in D_{n+1}$ and an $y\in E_n$ such that $\rho(x,y)< \frac{1}{n(n+1)}$, and by the previous inequality, this means that
$\rho(y, F)< \frac{1}{n}$ which is a contradiction since we assumed that $y$ is an element of $E_n$.

Comment: Thanks very much. Now it's clear. Can you help me why $\nu(E_{n+1})=\nu(D_{2n}\cup E_{2n})?$ I don't see it.

Comment: It doesn't say that. it says that this equality holds: $\nu(E_{2n+1})=\nu(D_{2n}\cup E_{2n})$. Now take a look again at the definition of $D_n$.